# Let the additive group of the integers be $(G = Z, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let the additive group of the integers be $(G = Z, +)$. Then $H = nℤ = ${$na;$ $a ∈ ℤ$ } is a subgroup of $G$, with $n ∈ N$

I need to solve this question, but I'm not understanding what the question asks, and what $H = nℤ = ${$na;$ $a ∈ ℤ$ } means. Could someone please make this question clearer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n\mathbb{Z}$ means the set of multiples of $n$. For example $2\mathbb{Z}$ refers to the set of even numbers.

The question is asking you to prove that the set of multiples of $n$ with the usual addition operations on integers is a subgroup of the group of.

Comment: Thanks, and what does {$na; a ∈ ℤ $} mean ?

Comment: $\{ na: a \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{ t : t = na \text{ where } a \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. It is the set of multiple of $n$. If $a=1$, $na = n$. If $a=2$, $na=2n$, and so on.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

just to prove $nZ$ is a group and is a subset of Z,

just like the even number is the subgroup of the integer